# Library not found for -lBVLinearGradient after upgrading my Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I'm trying to build my react-native project after upgrading my Xcode but I'm getting an error:

**"ld: library not found for -lBVLinearGradient
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"**

[Error screenshot in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzCqD.jpg)

I'm pretty sure this error is related to Cocoapods / Xcode because the app was building before the xcode upgrade.

**What I have done so far:**

- Use the .xcworkspace file
- Pod deintegrate / pod install (several times)
- Uninstall and reinstall the Linear-Gradient npm
- Setting the same iOS version in Deployment Target / info.plist
- Remove the '.a' files from Build Phases / Link Binary With Libraries

Do you guys have any other suggestion? I'm literally stuck at this bug for 3 days. And the worst part is that I have made everything I could find on internet.

Thanks

Comment: How did you solve it? I do not have any problems when I build for a device/simulator. But when I am trying to build with any iOS device(arm64, armv7), I am receiving the same error.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and stuck with this error. Were you able to resolve it?